# How to get both HTTP response body and Status when using Reactor Netty HTTP Client

Tags: project-reactor, reactor, reactor-netty

I am using the Reactor Netty HTTP client [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#http-client) as a stand alone dependency, ie not via `spring-webflux` because I do not want to drag in Spring related dependencies

As can be seen from the documentation it is possible to make a request that returns `HttpClientResponse`

```
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientResponse;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpClientResponse response =
                HttpClient.create()                   
                          .get()                      
                          .uri("http://example.com/") 
                          .response()                 
                          .block();
    }
}
```

Thing is `HttpClientResponse` only contains the headers and the staus. As can be seen from its Java Docs [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/snapshot/api/index.html?reactor/netty/http/client/HttpClientResponse.html)

Also from the example to consume data one can do

```
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String response =
                HttpClient.create()
                          .get()
                          .uri("http://example.com/")
                          .responseContent() 
                          .aggregate()       
                          .asString()        
                          .block();
    }
}
```

But this only returns the http entity data as string. No information about the headers nor status code.

The problem I have now is I need to make a request and get a response that gives me both the headers, status etc alongside with the http response body.

I cannot seem to find how. Any ideas?qw

Comment: Are you using `reactor-netty` as a standalone dependency? Or in the context of spring-webflux? If so you may want to use [`WebClient`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html) instead

Comment: As a stand alone dependency. I updated to question to include this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the following methods:

- [`Flux<V> response(BiFunction<HttpClientResponse,ByteBufFlux,Publisher<V>> receiver)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/http/client/HttpClient.ResponseReceiver.html#response-java.util.function.BiFunction-)
- [`Mono<V> responseSingle(BiFunction<HttpClientResponse, ByteBufMono, Mono<V>> receiver)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/http/client/HttpClient.ResponseReceiver.html#responseSingle-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

They allow you to access *response body*, *status*, and *http headers* simultaneously.

For example using the `responseSingle` method you can do the following:

```java
private Mono<Foo> getFoo() {
    return httpClient.get()
            .uri("foos/1")
            .responseSingle(
                    (response, bytes) ->
                            bytes.asString()
                                    .map(it -> new Foo(response.status().code(), it))
            );
}
```

*The code above translates the response into some domain object `Foo` defined as follows:*

```java
public static class Foo {
    int status;
    String response;

    public Foo(int status, String response) {
        this.status = status;
        this.response = response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Foo object is null when the http response does not have a body.  For example, if HttpStatus 403 is returned, the Foo object is null.  I was able to check response code and return just status.

```
(resp, bytes)-> {
  if (resp.status().code()=HttpResponseStatus.OK.code) {
        return bytes.asString().map(it->new Foo(resp.status(),it);
  } else {
        return Mono.just(new Foo(resp.status());
  }
}
```